# Error while trying installation using sudo apt-get install

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm getting this error while using `sudo apt-get install` command

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it
```

How do I  solve it?

Comment: Probably some background process is running. wait some minutes and try again.

Answer (score 0):

#### This should be used as last resort. If you use this carelessly you can end up with a broken system. Please try the [other](https://askubuntu.com/a/15436/44179) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/315791/44179) [first](https://askubuntu.com/a/878982/225694) before doing this.

You can delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

After then, updates the package lists :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/102084/121355)

Comment: Hey @efthialex it has been solved my probllem long back by using the above commands, when i tried to installl 'apt-get install vim' same problem occured so that's the reason i shared those here. even i got those commands from google search dont know exactly from where it's quite long back.

Comment: @efthialex, your edit was fine and a clear improvement to this post. Thanks! Kaushik, please see the other options mentioned. Yes, this approach can sometimes help, but it should always be the last resort since it can actually break things.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to reconfigure all unpacked but unconfigured packages by typing the following into a terminal :

```
sudo dpkg reconfigure -a
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how/why this command will fix the problem? It is commonly frowned upon just giving commands without explanations.

Comment: Although this command might not solve the issue here, have you forgot a hyphen (`-`) between `dpkg reconfigure`?